# How to undo a merged branch and then push it to Github

Tags: git, github

Please look at the following screenshot:

[image]

I'd like to delete the merged branch from my history.

I actually managed to achieve this myself by resetting the `load-helm-function` branch to 2 steps back and then cherry pick the commit `set 'spacemacs/inet-helm...` commit.

The real problem is that I wasn't able to push the `load-helm-option` branch because it's behind origin. After pulling the `origin/load-helm-option` I went back to square one.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After resetting the head of the branch back, you need to force push to GitHub to overwrite the changes there

Follow your original steps to reset the branch back to the correct commit and then `git push -f origin load-helm-function` to overwrite the remote.